# How to submit parameters by hyperlink-url and retrieve them in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, href

Carrying values in a while cycle, each value is extracted from a SQL table, and I need to carry em in a  since I'm making a list of items purchased from a specific client. I'm using this line for the href url:

```
    echo "<table width=1200 style align=left>";
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs3)){
$space = array("");
$text=$row3['description'];
$dash="_";
$url = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "_", $text);
$url= "".$url.".php";

echo "<tr><td colspan=2 style align=center><span class=font>" . $row3['relid'] . "</span></td><td width=132 style align=center><span class=font>" . $row3['invoiceid'] . "</span></td><td width=400 style align=center <span class=font><a href=$url>" . $row3['description'] . "</span></A></td><td width=132 style align=right><span class=font>" . $row3['amount'] . "</span></td><td width=132 style align=center><span class=font>Pendiente</span></td><td width=132 style align=left><span class=font>" . $row3['duedate'] . "</span></td></tr>";
}
mysqli_close($con3);
echo "</table>";
echo"<table width=1200>";
echo "  <tr class=font>
<td width=1200 height=22 colspan=7  background=border-green-horizontal.png>&nbsp;</td>
```

";

I'm generating the url from the Description I extract from the database but I need to carry the Order ID, Client ID, etc from the specific row.
Each variable is needs to be carried to a form where the user will fill some fields regarding the product the client bought (Medical Test Results), and I need those variables to mark as "Done" so It won't show up again on the list.

Comment: So where's the question?

Comment: How I can actually carry those variables to the other form?

Comment: Ok, why would you "carry" order ID, client ID from that specific row instead the ID of the row itself? And then, you query the db again and obtain info you need.

Comment: I'm using those ID's to take some other data from 3 different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix these syntax errors, report back if still broken.

```
<td width=400 style align=center <span class=font><a href=$url>" . $row3['description'] . "</span></a></td>
```

-->

```
"<td width=400 style align='center'><span class='font'><a href='$url'>" . $row3['description'] . "</span></a></td>"
```

### EDIT:

Do you mean how to append a var to an url, so it can be retrived on the called page?
You can append the var to the url by `echo "<a href='{$url}?id={$var}'>`.

On the called page, you can read it by `$_GET['id']`

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is on an echo, its a php script generating a table.

Comment: @ErickLeveron That was obvious from the `. $row3['description'] .` part. Did you try the syntax fix?

Comment: My testing server is down, i'll fix em right away, but can you help me with the variables?

Comment: I would, if I´d know what the question is. If you iterate the rows with `while`, every row will be displayed only once. Sorry - try to make your point clearer.

Comment: Ok, I need to save each row ID's so when I click on the description, it will take me to the form where I add some other information, but with it's proper ID's, so, How do I save every row ID's and use them in the the next form? Sorry about my vague response, my english is really "rusted".

Comment: @ErickLeveron Adapted my answer.